# How to assess change in obesity levels pre and post intervention where obesity is an ordinal variable?

Tags: categorical-data

I'm looking at changes in child obesity prevalence as well as other weight categories following an intervention. I'm trying to figure out which test to use for changes in a categorical dependent variable (I assigned values of 1-5 for children who were severely obese, obese, overweight, normal, underweight) pre and post intervention.

Answer (score 6):

Chances are that your weights came from a continuous measure of BMI. Hence you should *not* categorize it for statistical analysis, and you should just directly use BMI as a continuous outcome: this gives your statistical test more power to detect a difference in average BMI pre/post intervention. If there's no control group, you can just use a paired t-test to determine differences, however that test is biased by design due to the Hawthorne effect. Is there a control group in these data?

Comment: I'd second the answer of @AdamO.  In addition, you need to choose the measure of obesity that reflects the disease or outcome risk of interest.  In some cases this is BMI; in other cases it is waist circumference or weight.  But never categorize a legitimate continuous variable.

Comment: thank you for your responses. it's correct i used BMI-SDS, and this analysis is based on retrospective data so i did not have any influence on the measure of obesity used. there were no control groups, and i originally used a repeated measures ANOVA to determine changes in BMI-SDS for each weight category. I guess I'm a little confused on the best approach for determining changes in prevalence pre and post among weight categories (these are determined by centile ranking based on a reference population).

Comment: Essentially I now know if significant changes in BMI-SDS occurred in each weight category, and I know there were shifts in prevalence among each weight category. I'm just trying to figure out the best way to organize the data to determine if the shifting of weight categories (prevalence changes) were significant.

Comment: I just had a thought - I could do a repeated measures ANOVA for changes in percentile for this, correct?

Comment: Are you adjusting for other covariates in this analysis?

Comment: I am adjusting for gender.

Comment: Well since gender is constant within pairs (i.e. nobody changes gender in between intervention), you don't need to worry about adjusting for it. Just use a pre-post paired t test. Unless you believe gender *mediates* the effect of the intervention.

Comment: Thank you, Adam. You're suggesting a pre-post paired t test of percentiles?

Comment: No, my and Professor Harrell's comments have clearly suggested using continuous BMI as the outcome.